# Split-Path with Root UNC Directory

Tags: string, powershell, path, unc

So I've got a UNC path like so:

```
\\server\folder
```

I want to get just the path to server, eg `\\server`.
`Split-Path "\\server\folder" -Parent` returns `""`.  Anything I try which deals with the root, fails.
For example, `Get-Item "\\server"` fails too.

How can I safely get the path of `\\server` from `\\server\\folder` in PowerShell?

Comment: Is this Server Fault post any use? http://serverfault.com/questions/297690/how-to-split-parent-path-of-a-unc-path-by-using-powershell

Comment: Not really, Split-Path etc work fine for a path of the form "\\server\folder1\folder2"

Comment: For a UNC path, the root directory is the servername + the share name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By using the `System.Uri` class and querying its `host` property:

```
$uri = new-object System.Uri("\\server\folder")
$uri.host # add "\\" in front to get exactly what you asked
```

Note: For a UNC path, the root directory is the servername plus the share name part.

Comment: I like casting things using the URI type over New-Object but +1 `$URI = [URI]"\\Server\Folder"` `$URI.Host`

Answer (score 2):

An example using regular expressions:

```
'\\server\share' -replace '(?<!\\)\\\w+'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullpath = "\\server\folder"
$parentpath = "\\" + [string]::join("\",$fullpath.Split("\")[2])
$parentpath 
\\server
```

Comment: $parentPath = "\\" + [string]::join("\",$fullPath.Split("\")[2..3])